# SSRS with SSAS connection - Error after changing parameters -invalid Syntax for Public

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssas, mdx

I'm currently working at a SSRS Report who use a SSAS Connection with Shared dataset.
I changed the parameter in the shared dataset, changed the input parameter and the parameter in Report dataset

If I wanna preview it , I get the error

> The Execution failed for the shared data set 'Bids'.
> Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'
> Invalid Synatx for Public. (Sales)

i'm not used to do SSRS report with a SSAS data conection so i dont really know what to do

Did i forgot something?

for addition here's the MDX code for the Bids dataset that we created in the Query Designer of SSRS

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Error Count] }
       ON COLUMNS,
       NON EMPTY { ([Erroneous Bids].[Bid Link].[Bid Link].ALLMEMBERS 
               * [Erroneous Bids].[Bid].[Bid].ALLMEMBERS
               * [Erroneous Bids].[Sales Line].[Sales Line].ALLMEMBERS
               * [Erroneous Bids].[Probability].[Probability].ALLMEMBERS
               * [Erroneous Bids].[Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS
               * [Erroneous Bids].[Bid Error].[Bid Error].ALLMEMBERS 
               * [Erroneous Bids].[Sales Manager].[Sales Manager].ALLMEMBERS
               * [Erroneous Bids].[Severity].[Severity].ALLMEMBERS
               * [Erroneous Bids].[SalesTeam].[SalesTeam].ALLMEMBERS
              ) }
       DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_VALUE, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME
       ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@ErroneousBidsSalesTeam, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
    FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@ErroneousBidsSalesManager, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS
        FROM [Model]))
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

Comment: I would not think this is related to the MDX statement, but rather to SSRS. If you look at the SSRS report source, can you find something like `public` or `Sales` that looks as if it could be the cause of the error?

Comment: i did "found" the solution (or a workaround) by myself. i Kinda forgot  that defining parameters in the same dataset as the results dataset doesnt make any sense. so heres to that